# touchpad suddenly not working on 22.10

Tags: drivers, touchpad

I have been using ubuntu 22.10 for months with no problems but today after a restart the touchpad no longer works!

Touchpad is not present in the "touchpad and mouse" settings page and running `sudo lspci | grep synaptics` returns nothing!

Any ideas on what I can do (other than a fresh install of ubuntu)?

update #1:
I rolled back to an older kernel version but it had no effect on the problem.

update #2: my machine has dual boot setup, on windows touchpad works.

partial solution: found the solution with these commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

no idea why this worked! also, the touchpad works but none of the gestures work including two-finger scrolling!

system info:

```
           .-/+oossssoo+/-.               hasan@hasan-ThinkPad-E14-Gen-4 
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`           ------------------------------ 
      -+ssssssssssssssssssyyssss+-         OS: Ubuntu 22.10 x86_64 
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       Host: 21E30086TX ThinkPad E14 Gen 4 
   /ssssssssssshdmmNNmmyNMMMMhssssss/      Kernel: 5.19.0-43-generic 
  +ssssssssshmydMMMMMMMNddddyssssssss+     Uptime: 12 mins 
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhmNMMMNhssssssss/    Packages: 2000 (dpkg), 44 (brew), 20 
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Shell: zsh 5.9 
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   Resolution: 1920x1080 
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   DE: GNOME 43.1 
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   WM: Mutter 
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   WM Theme: Adwaita 
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Theme: Yaru-red-dark [GTK2/3] 
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhdNMMMNhssssssss/    Icons: Yaru-red-dark [GTK2/3] 
  +sssssssssdmydMMMMMMMMddddyssssssss+     Terminal: gnome-terminal 
   /ssssssssssshdmNNNNmyNMMMMhssssss/      CPU: 12th Gen Intel i5-1235U (12) @  
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       GPU: Intel Alder Lake-UP3 GT2 [Iris  
      -+sssssssssssssssssyyyssss+-         Memory: 3944MiB / 15676MiB
```

```
❯ xinput list                     
WARNING: running xinput against an Xwayland server. See the xinput man page for details.
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer:14                       id=6    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-relative-pointer:14              id=7    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer-gestures:14              id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ xwayland-keyboard:14                      id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Comment: Can you boot up a previous kernel?

Comment: i just did, touchpad still not working!

Comment: no idea why a question like this would get a down vote, but ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this odd problem by removing my external mouse and restarting.

just to be clear, I have started and restarted my machine with an external mouse many times with no issues but this time it created this strange behavior!